# Heroku TypeError: parse_requirements() missing 1 required keyword argument: 'session'

Tags: python, heroku, pip

I am trying to migeate an app to the cedar-14 stack from cedar on Heroku. In my requirements.txt file I have:

```
....
robobrowser==0.5.1
....
```

When I try to deploy by pushing the project to heroku I get:

```
Collecting robobrowser==0.5.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 17))
     Downloading robobrowser-0.5.1.tar.gz
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
         File "/tmp/pip-build-PqCF2A/robobrowser/setup.py", line 38, in <module>
           for requirement in parse_requirements('requirements.txt')
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_file.py", line 19, in parse_requirements
           "parse_requirements() missing 1 required keyword argument: "
       TypeError: parse_requirements() missing 1 required keyword argument: 'session'
       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
       Traceback (most recent call last):

         File "<string>", line 20, in <module>

         File "/tmp/pip-build-PqCF2A/robobrowser/setup.py", line 38, in <module>

           for requirement in parse_requirements('requirements.txt')

         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_file.py", line 19, in parse_requirements

           "parse_requirements() missing 1 required keyword argument: "

       TypeError: parse_requirements() missing 1 required keyword argument: 'session'

       ----------------------------------------
       Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-PqCF2A/robobrowser
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2422

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an open issue and a pull request in the `robobrowser`'s github issue tracker:

- [Updated requirements for pip 6.0+ to include a session](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser/pull/32)

Either wait for it being merged, or install `robobrowser` from the fork:

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/xxinfinityxx/robobrowser
```

---

Downgrading `pip` could also be an option, but I'm not sure if you have control over which pip version to use on heroku.

Comment: Thank you alecxe, but how would I get the forked version into heroku? I thought this had to be done by the requirements.txt .

Comment: @user61629 yup, you can add `git+git://github.com/xxinfinityxx/robobrowser` line to the list of your requirements.

Answer (score 16):

I ran into this problem installing wabbit_wappa for Python. I 'fixed' it by changing a line in setup.py from:

```
install_reqs = parse_requirements('requirements.txt')
```

to

```
install_reqs = parse_requirements('requirements.txt', session=False)
```

and it installed just fine.

Comment: Another stop gap in the code that does i dunno what :) Makes the underlying systems stop complaining about nothing I guess.

Answer (score 4):

Try updating pip:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

This fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have the current newest version of pip, and this did it for me:

```
install_requirements = parse_requirements('requirements.txt', session=pip.download.PipSession())
```